# jQuery calculate position of item in scrollable window and scroll to it

Tags: javascript, jquery

there. I have a list of items (users) in a popup. This list is in a scrollable div.
I want to make a search box that, using jQuery and Javascript, calculates the position of the 
desired user in this list and then scrolls to it. Basically, this is what I want:

```
function goToUser(userName) {
    var userPosition = getPosition(userName);
    $('#myContainer').scrollTop(userPosition);
}

function getPosition(userName){
    // ?????
}
```

Anyone had such a problem before ?  Thank you.

This is the partial view I use for the popup:

```
@using (@Html.BeginForm())
{
<div class="popupTitle">
    Choose user(s)
</div>
<div style="height: 400px; overflow: scroll" class="popupNotifications">
    @foreach (var user in Model.Users)
    {
        <div>
            <input id="Users-@user.id" name="targetIds" type="checkbox" value="@user.id" @if(Model.TargetIds != null && Model.TargetIds.Contains(user.id)){<text>checked="checked"</text>} />
            <label for="Users-@user.id" style="cursor: pointer;">@user.name</label>
        </div> 
    }
</div>
<div class="popupButtons">
    <input type="button" class="button" value="Save" onclick="GetValues(Notifications_UsersPopupHolder)" />
    <input type="button" class="button" value="Cancel" onclick="Cancel(Notifications_UsersPopupHolder)" />
</div>
```

}

Comment: this could be an overhead, but just in case you'd be lazy to code the math: http://flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all your items in the list is the same height you can calculate by (index + 1) * height of item.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `$(element).scrollIntoView()`?

I think your code would look like this (no need for a getPosition function):

```
function goToUser(userName){
    $('div.popupNotifications input#' + username).closest('div').scrollIntoView();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `offset().top` of the specific element.

```
function goToUser(userName) {
    var userPosition = getPosition(userName);
    $('.popupNotifications').scrollTop(userPosition);
}

function getPosition(userName){
    return $('.popupNotifications label:contains(' + userName + ')').offset().top;
}
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jqLFF/)

Answer (score 0):

You could assign the element containing your user an ID or some class that identifies it (either id="user1" or class="user1")

Then you can simply use

```
$('#elementcontainingusers').scrollTop($('#user1').position().top);
```